# How can i correctly use the python of the anaconda environment when I use "rosrun" to run a python file in ROS Noetic

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros

In terminal(activated environment), I input`python`, then input`import scipy && print(scipy.__version__)`, I can get correct output form screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MDQ2.png) However, when I use `rosrun scripy_name.py` (this file'content is also`import scipy && print(scipy.__version__)`)in the same terminal, the terminal display`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy', I'm confusing about this.`

Why I encounter this problem？
How can I fix it？